# call back in spring file upload

Tags: java, javascript, iframe, spring-mvc, file-upload

i have followed [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/) to upload file to server. the file is getting uploaded but after uploading the file it gives the page name as the filename.extension.jsp and gives `HTTP Status 404` here is the screen shot : 
[image: After uploading the file]

But i want to show the user only the status message saying `File is uploaded. how to do this?`

Here is my spring controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments_FileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createComments(
            @RequestParam("CIMtrek_daily_originator_comments") MultipartFile uploadItem,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        String uploadedFileName = "";
        try {
            String fileName = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            if (uploadItem.getSize() > 0) {
                inputStream = uploadItem.getInputStream();
                fileName = request.getRealPath("") + "/resources/Attachment/"+uploadItem.getOriginalFilename();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                int readBytes = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
                while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            }
            uploadedFileName = uploadItem.getOriginalFilename();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return uploadedFileName;
    }
```

Please help me to find,

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Anto you can do it somethig like this,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments_FileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createComments(
        @RequestParam("CIMtrek_daily_originator_comments") MultipartFile uploadItem,
        HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap map) {
    String uploadedFileName = "";

     ...

        uploadedFileName = uploadItem.getOriginalFilename();
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if("" != uploadedFileName || null != uploadedFileName) {
            map.put("message", new String("File is uploaded."));
        } else {
            map.put("message", new String("File is not uploaded."));
        }
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return uploadedFileName;
}
```

And JSP you put

```
<c:out value="${message}"></c:out>
```

**I hope help you :)**

Comment: Thanks hekomobile, it is working now but the response goes to another tab now when i save the form.

Comment: I am sorry when i upvote your answer it is not getting upvoted :(